# Android: Dimming navigation buttons

Tags: android, button, navigationbar

I'm trying to dim the navigation buttons (Back, Home, etc) on Honeycomb+.  It seems like this should do the trick, but it doesn't work for me:

```
protected void onResume( )
{
    super.onResume();

    View v = findViewById( android.R.id.content );
    if ( v != null )
        v.setSystemUiVisibility( isNightVision() ? View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                                                  :View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE );
}
```

I have some evidence that I'm doing this right because if I use SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION rather than SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE, the navigation bar does hide.

I'm testing on a Nexus 7 and at first I though maybe that device just doesn't support this option.  However, with the Kindle app the buttons are dimmed down to dots so I assume this is possible.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do in one of my applications:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried that too and it also doesn't work.  I assume it must have something to do with the app's setup or maybe my device's setup.  But for the life of me I have no idea what that could be.

Comment: OK, I just tried this with a simple test application and it does work there.  Now to start trying to figure out why it doesn't work in the real application.

Comment: I noticed an interesting behaviour. Sometimes it works, using the code line above, sometimes it doesn't. What helped me, is to schedule a timer in onCreate, with a delay of 100ms, which executes that specific line of code (API 16 on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I figured this out.  Our app is somewhat complex in that it has a Java library  (where I'm trying to dim the buttons), a native C library and several shell apps that use the libraries.

It looks like I needed to place:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

In the library manifest as well as the shell manifest.

I also needed to set target SDK to 11 in the properties for the library and the shells.

I think previously I had only done this in the library, but having it in the shells was needed to get the feature to actually work.